# VNC and keyboard mapping

Tags: vnc, vncserver

I have tight vnc server installed on SCO Unix. Is there any way to provide VNC with custom keyboard mapping file, without precompilling the sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the vnc xstartup script (~/.vnc/xstartup) to alter vnc's X configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I have provided xmodmap mapping file, and I'm loading it from ~/.vnc/xstartup